# Differing IDLE vs. command line behavior

Tags: python, linux, command-line, python-idle

I have the following code to stream an audio file:

```
import pafy
import vlc

url = "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dQw4w9WgXcQ"
audio = pafy.new(url)
best = audio.getbestaudio()
playurl = best.url

Instance = vlc.Instance()
player = Instance.media_player_new()
Media = Instance.media_new(playurl)
Media.get_mrl()
player.set_media(Media)
player.play()
```

This code runs fine from the python IDLE, but if I attempt to run it by calling it in the command line (`python main.py`), it doesn't ever play the audio. I've done some debugging and determined that the issue is with the final line, `player.play()`. Does anyone know what's going on here?

Comment: The IDLE doc has a section on IDLE/command-line differences, but I can't think of any that should affect this code.  I would try adding some debug prints and then running both ways.  For instance, before player.play, "print(player, vars(player))".  If you discover an answer, please direct a comment to me with @terryjanreedy so I can decide if any change to IDLE or its doc is indicated.

Comment: I had previously done some debugging and determined that the issue was with the final line, player.play(). I should have included this in my initial question, and I updated the question to reflect this.